# MVEL Lambda and closure in the strict mode typing

Tags: lambda, mvel

I try tu use MVEL in a strict mode but an error occurs and i don't understand why!

Here is my unitary test:

```
@Test
public void testMVEL(){
 String any = "def any(l, m) { for (ee : l) { if (m(ee)) return true;} return false; } \n";
    String cond = "if  (any({1,2,3,50,99} ,  def (i) {i > 100}))  true;  false;";
    ParserContext ctx = new ParserContext();
    ctx.setStrictTypeEnforcement(true);
    Serializable compiled = MVEL.compileExpression(any + cond, ctx);
    boolean res = MVEL.executeExpression(compiled,new HashMap(), Boolean.class);
    Assert.assertFalse(res);
}
```

The error is :

```
[Error: unqualified type in strict mode for: )]
[Near : {... if  (any({1,2,3,50,99} ,  def (i) {i > 100}))  true;  false; ....}]
                                                       ^
[Line: 2, Column: 44]
at org.mvel2.compiler.PropertyVerifier.getBeanProperty(PropertyVerifier.java:307)
at org.mvel2.compiler.PropertyVerifier.analyze(PropertyVerifier.java:117)
at org.mvel2.compiler.ExpressionCompiler.verify(ExpressionCompiler.java:381)
at org.mvel2.compiler.ExpressionCompiler._compile(ExpressionCompiler.java:273)
at org.mvel2.util.ParseTools.subCompileExpression(ParseTools.java:2119)
at org.mvel2.ast.IfNode.<init>(IfNode.java:58)
at org.mvel2.compiler.AbstractParser.createBlockToken(AbstractParser.java:1498)
at org.mvel2.compiler.AbstractParser._captureBlock(AbstractParser.java:1701)
at org.mvel2.compiler.AbstractParser.captureCodeBlock(AbstractParser.java:1543)
at org.mvel2.compiler.AbstractParser.nextToken(AbstractParser.java:380)
at org.mvel2.compiler.ExpressionCompiler._compile(ExpressionCompiler.java:128)
at org.mvel2.compiler.ExpressionCompiler.compile(ExpressionCompiler.java:62)
at org.mvel2.MVEL.compileExpression(MVEL.java:810)
```

Bug?